# C# Install and run .exe issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, executable

I have a c# console application. It is published to a UNC path where it will be executed from. When I double click on setup.exe from the UNC, where it is published, I get Application Install security warning.

Publisher cannot be verified.Are you sure you want to install this application?

I click on Install button and it ran the .exe file. I could see the o/p. Everything is fine. Then  Next time when I double click on the same setup.exe, I neither got Application Install Security warning nor doublicking setup.exe gave me the result that was expected from my application.

I m using Visual studio 2010. I want to know how would I bypass Application Install security warning in the first place? Eveytime when I double click setup.exe, it should give me the o/p w/o any warning signs. 
Right now I have to do uninstall program, then double click the exe to make it run and give my o/p.
I m sure there must be a way to not to uninstall program, then double click .exe to run it. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: setup.exe file gets generated when I click on Build tab-->publish to a specified UNC path.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into code signing.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/secureapps/archive/2007/01/25/code-signing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Installing from a network share, unless the application is signed by a certificate that is installed in the trusted certificate store of the suer installing, will always present the security warning.  Try installing the application using Click-Once deployment and when deploying, specify that the application must be downloaded everytime versus being installed into the control panel.  This will prevent users from keeping old copies on their desktops and won't give out any security warnings.

**Edit for ClickOnce Questions and Code Signing**

[Click Once information at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Code Signing from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Josh- Can you please provide further details on 'how-to' on signing the application by a certificate, Click-Once deployment, how to specify that the application must be downloaded everytime versus being installed into the control panel? I m new to these things. I will greatly appreciate your help in this area. Thanks.